# How to process unclaimed payments with PayPal sandbox?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

Many questions related are on the web, but nothing seems to solve the problem. I want to integrate PayPal IPN into my website and would like to test it with sandbox first. I have created 2 sandbox accounts - 1 for merchant and 1 for buyer.

I have payed with buyer's account.

```
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd"           value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business"      value="...merchant's snadbox email....">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name"     value="Huts For The Track">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number"   value="NZ-001">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount"        value="2.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping"   value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="return"        value="...some url...">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="...some url...">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url"    value="...someurl...">                                                          
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="lc"            value="US">
```

Afterwards,

- in buyer's sandbox account the payment are shown as **Unclaimed.**
- I have logged into merchant's sandbox account (with the same "...merchant's sandbox email...." that I sent in the code above). But, no received payment is shown in merchant's account (and his balance has not changed)
- The IPN was not sent to my server (probably since the merchant did not receive the payment)

How can this be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

While you have not provided many details in your question to help us help you, one likely cause would be having the 'business' parameter wrong in making your payment, such that you did not in fact pay the seller account you thought you were paying but instead paid to an email that does not yet exist as a PayPal account (in the sandbox). Thus the payment cannot be claimed until that email is signed up.

There is no way that only half a payment exists (e.g. sender without receiver) in PayPal. So if the buyer can see the payment, the sending side went *somewhere*, even if that is only a "holding record" inside PayPal being held on behalf on an un-signed-up email address. :)

Comment: Thank you @geewiz. Actually, I did create such merchant account and logged to it. Please see my edited question

Comment: You would not be sent an IPN if the merchant was not set up AND configured to request IPNs!) at the time of the payment. That is how IPNs work; they are only sent when the merchant requests them & provides enough information for them to be delivered.

Comment: Additionally, if you really have created the matching account -- same email as the payment was sent to -- and that payment still shows as pending in the buyer account, then the payment WILL show up as unclaimed in the receiving account's history. It will not credit into their balance until they claim/accept it (which seems natural enough, right?). You may have to ensure the email is verified by the receiving account for the payment to show up if you have not yet done so. But the liklihood that you have discovered a new bug that causes seller-side transactions to vanish is near zero.

Comment: I seem to figured this problem partially: developers -> dashboard -> sandbox -> accounts. When I pressed "Profile" on my seller's account, I got a msg that there was an error while creation of the account. I hace deleted the account and created a new one and then performed the payment - it worked ! :)

Comment: i am also facing this problem since i have created account on sandbox paypal. Do not know how to resolve it.